# Managing monitoring-style callbacks between Flex and Javascript

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, design-patterns

We've currently got some Javascript code that relies on Flex to do some of the heavy lifting via ExternalInterface callbacks.  It's not the prettiest thing in the world but it works.  On the Flex side we define something like this (remoteCall is a wrapper with typical RemoteObject behavior):

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("doOperation",
    function(data:String, windowId:String):void { doOperation(data, windowId) });

private function doOperation(data:String, windowId:String):void {
    remoteService.remoteCall(data, function(e:ResultEvent):void {
        ExternalInterface.call("doOperationComplete", windowId, e.result);
    });
}
```

and on the Javascript side we have:

```
function doOperationComplete(windowId, result) {
    var win = windowHandles[windowId];
    win.handleResult(result);
}
```

This works fine for most of our use cases, but I'm about to implement some basic task monitoring and I'm hoping there is a better way.  If I start down the same path as above I end up with a scenario where there is a JS -> Flex call to get a task status.  That call returns void, and when that call is complete, there is a Flex -> JS call to give JS the task status.  JS then needs to look at the status and take some action: give up, do something with the result, check status again after delay (Another JS -> Flex, Flex -> JS cycle).

I haven't started coding this yet, but it seems like it will get pretty hairy pretty quickly, with managing multiple task, associating Flex calls to Javascript with the original callbacks, passing appropriately scoped data, etc.

Is there a good alternative?  Some sort of Javascript task plugin that is designed for this sort of callback scenario?  Some design pattern that I'm overlooking?  Even some questionable technique like synchronizing remote service call so that `doOperation` returns task status instead of void?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do something like what Adobe did when they made IResponder.

Create an object when you make each call that is responsible for handling the call, and that has a "spot" for other data you'd like to associate with the specific call (like the AsyncToken in IResponder). That object shoud dispatch an event when the round trip is finished, and you can use the event to get a reference to the "spot" or the object that has that spot.

I've done this in pure Flash to make handling data reads/writes a bit cleaner. I wrapped Loader in another Class that remembers information about the call and generates a COMPLETE event when the call is complete. When I get the COMPLETE event, I read the associated info from the wrapper and dispose of the whole thing.

My recollection is that this is not identical to how the RemoteObject and HTTPService code work, but is similar in thought process. You can use F3 to go to the source code of one or the other and see exactly how Adobe handled it and try your hand at following the pattern for your own task.

Comment: I am hoping that there is already a framework to do this, or a pattern that would be sufficient without being this all-out IResponder equivalent.